Array dimensions must be known at compile time - Error Modelica
:)
Why do I get this error from Modelica:
Could not evaluate structural parameter (or constant): n which gives dimensions of array: capacitance. Array dimensions must be known at compile time.
[C:/OM122/OM64bit/OMCompiler/Compiler/NFFrontEnd/NFRangeIterator.mo: 245:11-246:61]: Internal error NFRangeIterator.hasNext got invalid range n
I am using the Array Components for the Heating Rod Example here: https://mbe.modelica.university/components/subsystems/heat_transfer
Best regards!
Modelica has a problem with the Array dimension, but isnt it fixed to the parameter n at the start?
    model Rod "Modeling discretized rod"
      import HTC=Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components;
      import Modelica.Units.SI;
    
      parameter Integer n(start=2,min=2) "Number of rod segments";
      parameter SI.Temperature T0 "Initial rod temperature";
      Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_a port_a
        "Thermal connector to ambient"
        annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}})));
      Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_b port_b
        "Thermal connector for rod end 'b'"
        annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));
      parameter SI.HeatCapacity C
        "Total heat capacity of element (= cp*m)";
      parameter SI.ThermalConductance G_wall
        "Thermal conductivity of wall";
      parameter SI.ThermalConductance G_rod
        "Thermal conductivity of rod";
      Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_a ambient
        "Thermal connector to ambient"
        annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-110},{10,-90}})));
    protected
      HTC.HeatCapacitor capacitance[n](each final C=C/n, each T(start=T0, fixed=true))
        annotation (Placement(transformation(
            extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
            origin={-30,20})));
      HTC.ThermalConductor wall[n](each final G=G_wall/n)
        annotation (Placement(transformation(
            extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
            rotation=90, origin={-30,-20})));
      HTC.ThermalConductor rod_conduction[n-1](each final G=G_rod*(n-1))
        annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
    equation
      for i in 1:n loop
        connect(capacitance[i].port, wall[i].port_b) "Capacitance to walls";
        connect(wall[i].port_a, ambient) "Walls to ambient";
      end for;
      for i in 1:n-1 loop
        connect(capacitance[i].port, rod_conduction[i].port_a)
          "Capacitance to next conduction";
        connect(capacitance[i+1].port, rod_conduction[i].port_b)
          "Capacitance to prev conduction";
      end for;
      connect(capacitance[1].port, port_a) "First capacitance to rod end";
      connect(capacitance[n].port, port_b) "Last capacitance to (other) rod end";
    end Rod;


Can you post the code that does not work for you? The models I from the linked website  seem to work flawlessly...

@MarkusA. Sure! :) I just changed the SI units to the way I got them taught. Maybe this is the error?
-> I edited the main question.

Using the code from the question and connecting three sources of temperature - one to each port - creates a perfectly running model in Dymola and OM 1.20.
You could try to give n a default value instead of just a start value, which would be parameter Integer n(min=2)=2 "Number of rod segments";
